# yii2 form into modal and rendering submit into the same modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have a form into a modal with a single 'new item' text input, a list of items and a submit button in it. Everything works perfectly, but I would like just after submitting to render again the same page (than has been updated) inside the same modal. Instead of thant it opens in the entire browser. I want all the operations to happen into the modal. All the examples I found seem to take the target out of the modal.

I've tried with renderAjax instead of render after saving this way ...

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    return $this->renderAjax('listar', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'pages' => $pages,
        'model' => $model
    ]);
} else {
    return $this->renderAjax('listar', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'pages' => $pages,
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

(That means deleting condition, I know.)

My view:

```
<div class="incidencias-listar">

    <?
    Pjax::begin([
        'enablePushState' => false,
        'id' => uniqid('pjax_') 
    ]);
    ?> 

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

            <div class="incidencias-form">

                <?
                $form = ActiveForm::begin();
                ?>

                <?
                echo $form->field($model, 'inc_descripcion')->textInput([
                    'maxlength' => true,
                    'tabindex' => '1' 
                ])->label('Descripción');
                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Añadir', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])?>
                </div>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <?
    echo ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'id' => uniqid('listview'),
        'options' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'list-wrapper',
            'id' => 'list-wrapper' 
        ],
        'layout' => '<div class="row paginador">{pager}</div><div class="row">{summary}</div><div>{items}</div>',
        'summary' => "<div class=\"col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12\"><div class=\"pull-left\"><br/>Mostrando <b>{begin}</b>-<b>{end}</b> de <b>{totalCount}</b> incidencias.<br/><br/></div></div>",

        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return $this->render('_list_item', [
                'model' => $model 
            ]);
        },
        'itemOptions' => [
            'class' => 'item' 
        ] 
    ]);
    ?>

    <? Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

I've also tried to create another ajax event fired by the inner submit button to display target into another modal.

Tried many choices without luck.

Comment: Have you tried Pjax? (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html)

Comment: Put it unsuccessfuly not only around ListView but around the whole view like in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do post with ajax and in the controller save the model without rendering.

In your _form:

```
$script = <<< JS
    $( document ).ready(function() {   

        $('#form').on('beforeSubmit', function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
           var form = $(this);
           var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]); 

            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: 'post',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {  
                    if(data === 'true')
                    {                        
                       // model save ok
                       $(form).trigger("reset");
                       $.pjax.reload({container:'#grid-pjax'}); 
                    } 

                },
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#FlashErrorModalContacto').html("Text Error").fadeIn(); // show error in a div
                }
            });

            return false;
        })

    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

And in your controller:

```
public function actionCreate(){
   $model = new Contacto();
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
      return 'true';

   } else {
      return 'false';
   }
}
```